# test pyautogui functions with unittest in python3.6

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest, pyautogui

I need to test functions that use pyautogui. For example, if pressing keyboard key "a" actually press an "a". How can I reproduce this? There is a way to capture the key that it´s been press?

Ideal if it works in Windows and Linux

Answer (score 0):

The PyAutoGUI unit tests have something like this. [See the TypewriteThread code for details.](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/blob/master/tests/test_pyautogui.py#L437) Set up a thread to wait a second and call `pyautogui.typewrite()`, then call `input()` to accept text. Make sure your window is in focus and the `typewrite()` thread ends by pressing Enter (the \n character).

```
import time
import threading

import pyautogui

class TypewriteThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, msg, interval=0.0):
        super(TypewriteThread, self).__init__()
        self.msg = msg
        self.interval = interval

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(0.25)
        pyautogui.typewrite(self.msg, self.interval)

t = TypewriteThread('Hello world!\n')
t.start()
response = input()
print(response == 'Hello world!')
```

Comment: I've changed it to a print(), which should print out True.